# How to use dependency of ProjectA in ProjectB in maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependency-management

I am working with Maven project and I have two projects, `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`. My `ProjectA` is a maven library whose pom looks like this:

**ProjectA POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.texture.partial</groupId>
        <artifactId>PartialPlatform</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5-RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.texture.transform.golden</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleClientProjectA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.partial.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>PartialKernel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.webres</groupId>
            <artifactId>WebResPartial</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.kernel</groupId>
            <artifactId>TextureServer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.kernel</groupId>
            <artifactId>Kernel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.v3jars.Houston</groupId>
            <artifactId>KerlDEL</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.kernel</groupId>
            <artifactId>pKerl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.kernel</groupId>
            <artifactId>pKerlCore</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.cglib</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.partial.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>ConfigWeb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.partial.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>PartialWeb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}"/com/googlecode/jmockit/jmockit/1.7/jmockit-1.7.jar</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <instrumentation>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/test/**/*.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </instrumentation>
                    <formats>
                        <format>xml</format>
                        <format>html</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In my above pom, `PartialKernel` is bringing older version of various Spring Framework dependencies like `spring-core`, `spring-web`. It is bringing `3.2.8.RELEASE` version and I want to use latest version of those two spring framework, which is `4.1.6.RELEASE`.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I need to use latest version since some classes are there in latest version only. So I added new version of these two libraries in my pom.xml as it is in my ProjectA. I have a static void main code which will test `ProjectA` functionality and that works fine without any issues.

Now I have `ProjectB` which also has same above pom as it is without latest version of spring dependency. In my `ProjectB` pom, I am having dependency of `ProjectA` and same code which will test functionality of `ProjectA` but whenever I run the same class in `ProjectB` I am always getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureCallback
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureCallback
```

All the latest spring related code which I am using is in `ProjectA` in which I already have latest version of spring. Sample Test code which I have is just to invoke `ProjectA` classes that's all to test it out.

**ProjectB POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.texture.partial</groupId>
        <artifactId>PartialPlatform</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5-RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.texture.transform.golden</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleTestClientProjectB</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.partial.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>PartialKernel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.webres</groupId>
            <artifactId>WebResPartial</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.kernel</groupId>
            <artifactId>TextureServer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.kernel</groupId>
            <artifactId>Kernel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.v3jars.Houston</groupId>
            <artifactId>KerlDEL</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.kernel</groupId>
            <artifactId>pKerl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.kernel</groupId>
            <artifactId>pKerlCore</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.cglib</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.partial.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>ConfigWeb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.partial.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>PartialWeb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.texture.transform.golden</groupId>
            <artifactId>SampleClientProjectA</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>    
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}"/com/googlecode/jmockit/jmockit/1.7/jmockit-1.7.jar</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <instrumentation>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/test/**/*.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </instrumentation>
                    <formats>
                        <format>xml</format>
                        <format>html</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But when I add latest version of spring dependency in my ProjectB, my test code starts working fine. And this is what I don't want. Is there any way, my ProjectB to start using whatever dependency I am using in ProjectA automatically? If they want to change it then they can override it in their code in ProjectB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to exclude the dependencies from the pom xml. here is the example.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.texture.partial.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>PartialKernel</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion> 
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried this already but didn't helped. I still get same exception in ProjectB code when I ran it.

Comment: sorry, but are you planning to run the project B from itself directly or are you trying to run the project A?

Comment: I have a main class in ProjectB which I am running it directly and that is giving me exception. And I have same main class as it is in ProjectA which works fine. So main class from ProjectB will run ProjectA.

Comment: ok. then i guess you would also need to update your project B pom.xml. I have removed the line in my answer that says you only need to remove it on project A.

Comment: But why? Can it not use latest spring version which I have already defined in ProjectA? Why I need to update ProjectB? Is there any way by which ProjectB can have latest spring dependency since it depends on ProjectA wtihout touching ProjectB at all?

Comment: i think i'm missing something here. but, from the project B pom.xml, i don't see any line on which the project B refer to the project A. from me it just like project B pom.xml is just a plain copy paste from project A pom.xml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75670/discussion-between-david-and-kucing-terbang).